# I need to be able to read a large CSV file to an Arduino Uno 600 bytes at a time

Tags: arduino-uno

I have a project where I have built a sensor network based on the arduino uno. It is a temp sensor and light sensor and an air flow meter.
I am taking readings 5 times a second and saving the data to a CSV file on an SD card.

After a period of time I need to stop sensing and send the data to a server using HTTP POST. As the CSV file is large I can only do this by reading the logfile 600 bytes at a time sending that data and then reading the next 600 bytes and so on.

I still cant figure out how to read the next 600 bytes of information from the files.

Do I need some kind of pointer to remember where in the file I stopped reading?

Comment: Just to clarify - I have all the code working for the sensors and datalogging I am having trouble reading the data from the SD card in order to POST it

Comment: Open a stream and send the data with appropriate buffer size (600 bytes)

Comment: Thanks Nkosi. I have looked at that but still cant figure out how to read the next 600 bytes of information from the file. Do I need some kind of pointer to remember where in the file I stopped reading?

Comment: Yes. do the read in a while look. You are reading the data in chunks so after each chunck you have to keep track of where you are. What language are you using. Not familiar with arduino per say but familiar with scenario.

Comment: Thanks Nkosi, I have written the code - its a variant of C as you suggest below and it is compliling correctly - I'll put it on the sensor later to ensure that it works as I want but looks good - again many thanks

Comment: Glad to help. Yeah I wasn't sure what language you were using so put what I found while doing some research. If when you check later it resolves your problem then mark as answer. Happy coding!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rough example of how to read file in chunks

```
File file = SD.open(filename, FILE_READ);
char buffer[600];
if(file) {  
    while(file.position() < file.size()) {
        int bytesRead = file.readBytes(buffer, sizeof(buffer));

        //Sudo code...
        // Post buffer 
    }
}
```